# Why is the error not being caught/handled in this "try...except" block?

Tags: python, try-catch

I have a function that finds the latitude and longitude of an input address. But since sometimes an address returns nothing (i.e., can't be found in Google maps), I want to remove words one by one from the address until it can finally return something. The code runs fine for all addresses, except a few, of which I am showing one below:

```
place = '033 SEGOVIA ST ILAWOD 2 DARAGA ALBAY PHILIPPINES'

while True:
    place = place.split(' ', 1)[1] # remove the first word from the address
    try:
        lat, lon, res = gmaps_geoencoder(place)
    except:
        place = place.split(' ', 1)[1]
        lat, lon, res = gmaps_geoencoder(place)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-174-5b96029e3dbf> in <module>()
      5     try:
----> 6         lat, lon, res = gmaps_geoencoder(place)
      7     except:

<ipython-input-1-3bfa8158ebff> in gmaps_geoencoder(address)
     12     res = req.json()
---> 13     result = res['results'][0]
     14     lat = result['geometry']['location']['lat']

IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-174-5b96029e3dbf> in <module>()
      7     except:
      8         place = place.split(' ', 1)[1]
----> 9         lat, lon, res = gmaps_geoencoder(place)

<ipython-input-1-3bfa8158ebff> in gmaps_geoencoder(address)
     11     req = requests.get(GOOGLE_MAPS_API_URL+'?address='+address+'&key='+API_key)
     12     res = req.json()
---> 13     result = res['results'][0]
     14     lat = result['geometry']['location']['lat']
     15     lon = result['geometry']['location']['lng']

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why can't it catch the exception for this address? And how come it does catch for most of the other addresses?

When I manually try the function, it works fine:

`gmaps_geoencoder('033 SEGOVIA ST ILAWOD 2 DARAGA ALBAY PHILIPPINES')` produces error,

`gmaps_geoencoder('SEGOVIA ST ILAWOD 2 DARAGA ALBAY PHILIPPINES')` produces error,

`gmaps_geoencoder('ST ILAWOD 2 DARAGA ALBAY PHILIPPINES')` produces error,

but `gmaps_geoencoder('ILAWOD 2 DARAGA ALBAY PHILIPPINES')` returns the location coordinates correctly.

**P.S.:** In case it matters, here's my function definition:

```
def gmaps_geoencoder(address):
    req = requests.get(GOOGLE_MAPS_API_URL+'?address='+address+'&key='+API_key)
    res = req.json()
    result = res['results'][0]
    lat = result['geometry']['location']['lat']
    lon = result['geometry']['location']['lng']
    return lat, lon, str(res)
```

Comment: Hey, I don't know what gmaps_geoencoder() is. Please attach the includes as well.

Comment: Ok, I've included the function definition in the question details, although it doesn't matter I think.

Comment: Well, I think it does catch your Exception. But in the except: you also get an Exception. I don't know how python should behave in that situation.

Comment: It does catch the first IndexError. The issue is that the code in your `except` block raises another IndexError that is not handled `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`

Comment: Also, make sure your request's results has content. The IndexError raises both times because `res['results']` appears to be an empty list when you try to access index 0 on it. Which in turn means that the Google Maps API does not seem to find results for the address you query it for.

Comment: @shmee Yes, I get that, but how do I handle it then? Also, how come it worked with other addresses, where it stripped out the address to only 1 or 2 words?

Comment: Well, for the latter question, you'll have to ask Google as to why their API does not return results for these queries. I can't tell :) As for how to handle this case: check if `res['results'] actually has elements in it before trying to access index 0: `if res['results']:`. You'll have to define a clean state and/or behavior for your code to handle such a situation. You cannot rely on the API to always return usable results

Comment: @Kristada673 Can you give more addresses that returns you nothing? I've reproduced your code and for some reasons it works well for the address you gave in the example.
I've used `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json` for the `GOOGLE_MAPS_API_URL`.

Comment: Same results with these addresses. I get the `lat` and `lng` but as the loop is never broken no matter if it succeds or not, I end up with exceptions when the sring is empty. [Eran Moshe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51473371/9962106) seems to be the good answer.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Maybe I'm getting null returns due to my location/internal network?

Comment: If you try to print `lat` and `lng` at each loop tick (right after the `gmaps_geoencoder()` calls), do you get any result?

Comment: Nah, I get blanks

Comment: print res in gmaps_geoencoder() and read the json result. see if you have your wanted lat and lng attributes. If so, you need to re-understand how to access them

Comment: @EranMoshe Yeah, I had already checked that before posting this question. `res` is empty for certain addresses for me.

Comment: @Kristada673 I've posted [the reproduction of your code](https://pastebin.com/2wArRA6T) I use and that works for me. Does it works for you too? (Don't forget to add your API key in the variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code raises another `Exception` in the except sub-code.

I'd go with this approach

```
while True:
    try:   
        lat, lon, res = gmaps_geoencoder(place)
    except:
        place = place.split(' ', 1)[1]
```

Do note that at some point the `try` succeed and you want to `break`. Also, `place` can come to an end (probably an empty list), and you either `break` at that point under the `except` sub-code or put it as a stop-term in the `while`

Last but not least, `except:` is highly not recommended to use without specific `Exceptions`. I'd suggest investigating on which `Exceptions` you want to catch there.

Here's a more processed code:

```
while len(place) > 1 :
    try:   
        lat, lon, res = gmaps_geoencoder(place)
        break
    except:
        place = place.split(' ', 1)[1]
```

I intentionally didn't write this code for you because I don't know exactly what you want to do with `lat, lon`. Do you want to get the first result? or lists of results? I left it for you with the basic structure that handle the "*Unknown*" exception.

Comment: I tried your first code, it keeps splitting the address until no more words are there, so its returns a `list index out of range` error. And the second code, just keeps running (its been 5 mins now); don't know what's up with that! P.S. I am NOT the one who gave you -1 for this answer :)

Comment: Well you must BREAK after the try succeed. And terminate the while once place is empty or = ''

Comment: Ok, the second code works with the `break` after the `try`. Thanks. But the first code still does not work.

Comment: Do note that you can keep process the so called "place" and get more results. when breaking after the try, you only get the first result you find. :>

Comment: That last one is still gonna break with an IndexError if the whole `place` has been fully iterated without ever having returned a match. ;) `place` is a string of non-zero length when your while loop tests it with `len(place) > 1`. During the last iteration, when `place` only contains 'PHILIPPINES', the condition is true, but when split at a whitespace character in the `except`, the returned list will not have a second element. That case might be unlikely in this scenario, but should be kept in mind.

Comment: Yes. I didn't know exactly in what scenarios you will encounter that's why I was reluctant to give you a full code that works. I wanted you to define the breaking conditions and what you want to do after the try succeeds..